# How to get related products in product page of WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I am having Entrada theme installed in my website.I am trying to get the related products by entering the related products in the linked product tab, but it is not working.

What are the function available to get the related products?

Comment: Look to this [following threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bwoocommerce%5d%20related%20products)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a built-in shortcode - `[related_products limit="5"]` , 'limit' is # of products to display.